# arraylist = 'this' is not available, in Android Studio while adding element in the arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am fetching the `json` and adding the element to the `arraylist`. But, the element is not being add in the `arraylist`. 
When I debugged, I found following at the debug point:
`arraylist='this' is not available`
I searched a lot but couldn't find the solution anywhere.

```
public class ProfileHeaderRepository {
    private Context context;
    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ProfileInfo>> mutableLiveData = new     MutableLiveData<>();
    private ArrayList<ProfileInfo> arrayList;

    public ProfileHeaderRepository(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<ProfileInfo>> getProfileDetails(){
        String url = ApplicationConstants.GET_PROFILE_HEADER;

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.get(0);
                        String name = jsonObject.getString("extra_info");
                        String image = jsonObject.getString("thumbnail");
                        ProfileInfo profileInfo = new ProfileInfo(name, image);
                        arrayList.add(profileInfo);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                mutableLiveData.postValue(arrayList);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            String key = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("KEY", null);
            headers.put("Authorization","TOKEN "+key);
            //return super.getHeaders();
            return headers;
        }
    };

    jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    return mutableLiveData;

    }
}
```

[image: Here, is the image of the debug console.]

Comment: This just means that the debugger apparently doesn't have access to the arrayList. To get around this, you could assign the arrayList to a local variable and then you'd be able to inspect it using the debugger

Comment: Use `arrayList.addAll(profileInfo)` instead of  `arrayList.add(profileInfo)`

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir, No you cannot do this because addAll() method is used to add elements of Collection in the specified list. Here, profileInfo is not a Collection.

Comment: oh i see, i assumed if it is list.